# Secure panel sharing in grafana3

Tags: grafana

I am looking for a way to automatically share graphs/panels/dashboards with a range of customers in grafana 3, but without the risk that the customers can access any other data from than grafana instance.

In grafana it’s possible to embed panels in iframes to share them on websites. That would be ideal for my use case.
For that auth:anonymous needs to be enabeld=true in the config. I’d like to know what the consequences are for that setting other than that my customers don’t need to be registered grafana users to access their graphs.

I do understand, that you can create organisations in grafana and anonymous users need to be registered with that. Now if I create an OrganisationA and an OrganisationB would that mean customerA does not have any access to the panels from customerB? And would it also mean that my customers are required to be registered grafana users?

What I don’t want is having to create a seperate grafana instance for every customer since they all share the same datasource and are linked to other dashboards.
Exporting pngs and uploading them hourly on a website would be a less desirable work around.

Can anyone help? I couldn’t find anything concerning these security questions but I am sure grafana is already used for this use case.
Or does anyone have experiences with alternative dashboard software to monitor server actions and data?

Here is the grafana docu concerning the config: http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/